# Extract columns of specific type in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that has a bunch of numeric and factor columns. I want all the non factor columns. Is there a way to extract them?
I tried something like

```
df[class(df)!="factor" ]
```

But no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, data frame is a list, so you might want to apply `class()` to every element of that list (i.e. to each column):

```
df[lapply(df,class)!="factor" ]
```

Answer (score 2):

An example with `Filter`:

```
df <- data.frame(as.factor(letters), a = runif(26), b=runif(26) )
Filter(Negate(is.factor), df)
```

Output:

```
> Filter(Negate(is.factor), df)
            a          b
1  0.04942200 0.85160817
2  0.96370499 0.77911640
3  0.66545208 0.33037229
4  0.19736620 0.54797165
5  0.15264687 0.72744035
6  0.86426399 0.88491690
...
...
```